# Understanding a power switch circuit that includes Schottky diodes at its input

Tags: power, switches, schematics, reverse-engineering

In the following design, I couldn't find the datasheet for the part U25.
All I could find from Orcad that chip part name is: G5027C.

Anyway, I don't have contact with the person who created this circuit, and I'm trying to understand the design in order to learn and try to use a similar design in other project.

This circuit is a part of reference design for a motherboard that includes a CPU that I want to implement in a motherboard of my own. It's my first motherboard project as a board designer, and I'm to understand this reference design in order to see how it makes sense in terms of signals names as described in datasheets.

As a start, I'm going through the power diagram and following the signals and trying to check mark that I understand the purpose of every signal.

Intuitively, I'd think that U25 is a PWR Switch whose purpose is to deliver "+VCCSTG_CPU" voltage once "GPPC_H_18_CPU_C10_GATE_N" signal is low.
When the signal is LOW, that corresponds to the N at the end of "GPPC_H_18_CPU_C10_GATE_N" signal name, that way the diode connected to it will pass current since pin 1 has a lower voltage that pin 2 (CR28).

Regarding the second diode, with the pin 2 name CR30, it will not conduct. Therefore the ON pin of the "PWR switch" will be low.

My question: What is the designer trying to achieve here with this mechanism? And is my initial analysis correct?

Note 1: Since some of the signals in this circuit come from the CPU, I need to take them into account and know what the best configuration is to use them. In this design, there is a suggested method of using diodes in order to control how CPU\PCH signals affect power delivery (in this case VCCSTG_CPU is the CPU Sustain Gated Power Rail). I want to make sure I understand the purpose of using these diodes, since it might be a standard mechanism that is used many times and could be helpful to implement it in my design, but surely after understanding it.

Note 2: In the OrCAD design, it's clear that U25 is a switch, and it logical regarding the pinout of the device.
I added screenshots that include all the details I have for this device.

[image: schematic]

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you don't know what it's used for and you can't recognize the chip and you have no accessible design notes, what is it about this circuit that you believe may be useful to you? At the moment your question doesn't make much sense. It reads like you think you might need something and maybe the circuit is what you need. Better to start again in my opinion and state what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Andyaka , thanks for your comment. I made an edit, I hope it's more clear now.

Comment: If you are looking at a reference design then look at the BoM/parts list to see what that part is. Nobody is going to make a guess based on what info you have provided.

Comment: @Andyaka, I have no BOM. all I have is an access to the Orcad Design to see what is the part number of the MFG. from a search in google I could see that this device falls under "Switches" category as I expected:

https://www.sager.com/g5027-4157989.html?utm_source=SupplyFrame&utm_medium=click&utm_campaign=sager-brand

Comment: Then you don't have a "reference design". That term is reserved for a full design tear-down in my opinion.

Comment: @Andyaka, you are right about not having the specific details about P/N and MFG. but usually that information should be clearly stated in OrCAD itself. which is not the case here. I think G5027C is a special P\N for some *supplier* and not the real MFG.
I'm looking for an answer assuming this device is a power switch, given all the info I provided to support my assumption.
 if it's not enough and it doesn't meet the community standards, please let me know to delete this question.